# about error of 'com.android.tools.r8.internal.q8: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-r8

I did to import a System App of `SystemUI` to `Android Studio Arctic Fox`, then occur this error,
what does this error mean?

Comment: Hi, I have added an answer below. If you can provide more information on how you imported `SystemUI` and the project setup I might be able to help futher with fixing this. The header jars should not be passed to D8, but only to javac. What might be the issue here is that `SystemUI` uses hidden APIs which are passed as a header jar. However, one thing to keep in mind is that the Android Platform setup has not been designed with Android Studio in mind, so there might be some work involved in getting it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is reported [here](https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/a5eb5d144af3a05d5ee428e0eb8caef9bab68d75/src/main/java/com/android/tools/r8/graph/LazyCfCode.java#387), and is caused by an invalid class file. As this code comes from the Android Platform, it could be that one of the input jars have been processed by [turbine](https://github.com/google/turbine)/[ijar] to produce a header jar.

Comment: yes, I changed the jar of javac/*.jar to fixed it! THX

Comment: Futher more, can u help me see this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69331560/how-to-let-framework-jar-compile-in-front-of-android-jar-on-android-studio-a