# how to let 'framework.jar' compile in front of 'android.jar' on Android Studio Arctic Fox

Tags: android, android-studio, frameworks, android-studio-arctic-fox

First, how to let the `framework.jar` compile in front of `android.jar` on `Android-Studio-Arctic-Fox` with `gradle 7.0.2` and `AGP-7.0.2`
Second is let Editor first to import from the `framework.jar` to fix it not display RED(cannot find some method or field or class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently not possible to override `android.jar` with classes from a custom jar - https://issuetracker.google.com/167750503. However, you could replace `android.jar` in the Android SDK with your own, and Android Studio and Android Gradle plugin will pick them up.

Alternatively, you can develop [Sdk Add-on](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update#adding-sites), and point your users to it. It will be automatically handled by Android Studio. Here is an [example](https://github.com/profusion/android-sdk-addon-example) of how to build one.

Comment: Do u know how to build `aar` file with `android.bp`?

Comment: @Fang you have to build it as android_library ([one](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/+/e942e32f97c482f70736d736be5eb23101ff0336/java/aar.go#481) & [two](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/+/e942e32f97c482f70736d736be5eb23101ff0336/java/aar.go#447))